# MySQL Use an In Clause With a Comma Delimited Column

Tags: mysql, query

I am trying to use a column that has a comma delimited list of values in an in clause.  I thought about doing a contains but it would not be correct when searching for single digit values.

Example:  1,5,12,14,16,15,18,19,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,40,41,43,44,45,47,48,49,51,53,54,55,56,57,59,61,62,63,64,65

This is the error that I am getting:

> ```
> [MySql.Data]  
> ErrorCode: -2147467259, Number: 1064  
> ErrorMessage: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that  
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near  
> 'cpei5.value' at line 12
> ```

Here is my query:

```
SELECT soi.*
FROM   sales_order_item soi
       INNER JOIN sales_order so
            ON  so.entity_id = soi.order_id
       INNER JOIN sales_order_address soa
            ON  soa.parent_id = so.entity_id
       INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity cpe
            ON  cpe.sku = soi.sku
       INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_text cpei5
            ON  cpei5.row_id = cpe.entity_id
       INNER JOIN eav_attribute ea5
            ON  ea5.attribute_code LIKE 'state_not_allowed'
            AND ea5.attribute_id = cpei5.attribute_id
WHERE  soa.address_type = 'shipping'
       AND date_add(so.created_at, interval 365 DAY) >= CURRENT_DATE()
       AND date_add(so.created_at, interval 365 DAY) <= date_add(CURRENT_DATE(), interval 30 DAY)
       AND cpe.type_id = 'simple'
       AND soa.region_id IN cpei5.value
```

Comment: Firstly, `IN` requires a parenthesised list of values on the RHS -- that's your syntax error. Once you fix that, you'll hit the second, semantic error: all it will see is a single value `'1,5,12,14,16,15,...,65'`, not a list, so your comparison won't work. You should have normalized your database properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
col IN (1,2,34)        -- A
col IN ("1,2,34")      -- B
col IN ("1","2","34")  -- C
```

Binding tends to produce B, but...
A and C have 3 choices, B has only one choice (a 6-character string)

Both A and C work if `col` is `INT`; C works if `col` is `VARCHAR`.

A, B, and C, *may* be able to use an `INDEX`.

```
FIND_IN_SET(col, "1,2,34")  -- D
```

Find_in_set has these characteristics:

- Easy to 'bind'
- Won't use an `INDEX`
- Works with strings or numbers.

Comment: The FIND_IN_SET is what worked.  Thanks so much.